# How does RoR scaffolding work with compound words?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is what I still don't understand (but probably should)... if I run this command:

script/generate scaffold FooFoo name:string submitted_on:datetime

How do I link to a the page that lets you view the list of FooFoo?

This doesn't seem to work, and every variant of it that I've tried doesn't work either:

```
<%= link_to "Mylink", foo_foos_path %>
```

Comment: When I generate that scaffold, the 'Back' link on show.html.erb is generated with foo_foos_path, and it works for me. What's happening for you? Is it generating the wrong URL? Raising an exception? Do you have the resource mapped in your config/routes.rb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks right to me. The `foo_foos_path` helper is generated by this line in `config/routes.rb`:

```
map.resources :foo_foos
```

Make sure that line was added by your scaffold generator.

Comment: Oh, I knew I needed to do that too... just wasn't thinking... Thanks